# How to parse following XML?

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to be able to parse the following XML on the iPhone. Could you please advise how I can do that? Thanks!

```
<XML>
  <ADD>
        <FOLDER>
              <SOMEDAYID>1</SOMEDAYID>
              <FOLDERNAME>Travel</FOLDERNAME>
              <FOLDERCOLOR>1</FOLDERCOLOR>
              <FolderStatus>1</FolderStatus>
        </FOLDER>
        <EVENTS>
              <EVENT>
                    <SOMEDAYID>2</SOMEDAYID>
                    <DESCRIPTION>U2 rockfestival...</DESCRIPTION>
                    <ISACTIVE>Y</ISACTIVE>
                    <ISDONE>N</ISDONE>
                    <ALERT>1</ALERT>
                    <TRIGGERTIME>2007381580</TRIGGERTIME>
                    <IMAGE>NOIMAGE</IMAGE>
                    <EventStatus>1</EventStatus>
              </EVENT>
        </EVENTS>
  </ADD>
  <EDIT>
        <FOLDER>
              <SOMEDAYID>2</SOMEDAYID>
              <FOLDERNAME>Entertainment</FOLDERNAME>
              <FOLDERCOLOR>2</FOLDERCOLOR>
              <FolderStatus>2</FolderStatus>
        </FOLDER>
        <EVENTS>
              <EVENT>
                    <SOMEDAYID>4</SOMEDAYID>
                    <DESCRIPTION>See HarryPotter</DESCRIPTION>
                    <ISACTIVE>N</ISACTIVE>
                    <ISDONE>Y</ISDONE>
                    <ALERT>1</ALERT>
                    <TRIGGERTIME>1287585716</TRIGGERTIME>
                    <IMAGE>NOIMAGE</IMAGE>
                    <EventStatus>2</EventStatus>
              </EVENT>
        </EVENTS>
  </EDIT>
  <REMOVE>
        <FOLDER>
              <SOMEDAYID>3</SOMEDAYID>
              <FOLDERNAME>Shopping</FOLDERNAME>
              <FOLDERCOLOR>3</FOLDERCOLOR>
              <FolderStatus>3</FolderStatus>
        </FOLDER>
        <EVENTS>
              <EVENT>
                    <SOMEDAYID>4</SOMEDAYID>
                    <DESCRIPTION>See HarryPotter</DESCRIPTION>
                    <ISACTIVE>N</ISACTIVE>
                    <ISDONE>Y</ISDONE>
                    <ALERT>1</ALERT>
                    <TRIGGERTIME>1287585716</TRIGGERTIME>
                    <IMAGE>NOIMAGE</IMAGE>
                    <EventStatus>2</EventStatus>
              </EVENT>
        </EVENTS>
  </REMOVE>
```

Comment: Hello Rupesh, Welcome to SO. You may want to first read the faq - http://stackoverflow.com/faq to understand the functioning and how to ask questions. You will need to format your question more appropriately and add the relevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the answers here [How to parse the following XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912277/how-to-parse-the-following-xml)